# Add Hyperlink with Variable to Mysql Table

Tags: php, sql, hyperlink

I would like to add a url to php table along with variable.
Any one please help me solving this.

See the comment description in table for further info.

```
<?php
        include('config.php');
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM pincode_data where pinCode='641028'";
        $result = mysql_query($qry) or die (mysql_error());
        echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr><td>Pincode:</td> <td><a href='pinview.php?pin=" . $pinCode . "'>".$row['pinCode'] . "</td></tr>"; //I want a hyperlink here along with pin number example url: pinview.php?pin=641028
                echo "<tr><td>Office Name:</td> <td>" . $row['postOffice'] . "</a></td>";
                echo "<tr><td>Office Type:</td> <td>".$row['OfficeType'] . " </td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td>Contact:</td> <td>".$row['contact'] . "</td></tr>"; 
                echo "<tr><td>Taluk:</td> <td>".$row['talukName'] . " </td></tr>"; 
                echo "<tr><td>District:</td> <td>".$row['districtName'] . " </td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td>State:</td> <td>".$row['stateName'] . "</td></tr>"; 
                echo "<tr><td>Postal Division:</td> <td>".$row['postalDivision'] . " </td></tr>"; 
                echo "<tr><td>Postal Region:</td> <td>".$row['postalRegion'] . " </td></tr>";
                echo "<td>Postal Circle:</td> <td>".$row['postalCircle'] . "</td> "; 
            } 
        echo "</table>";
        mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with this line you have to add `$row['pinCode']` instead of `$pinCode`

```
echo "<tr><td>Pincode:</td> <td><a href='pinview.php?pin=" . $row['pinCode'] . "'>".$row['pinCode'] . "</td></tr>";
```